# Update validation for unique attribute

Tags: laravel, controller, unique

I have this function update in my controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $siswa = Siswa::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'nisn'=>'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn'.$request->input('nisn'),
        'nama_siswa'=>'required|string|max:30', 
        'tgl_lahir'=>'required|date',
        'jns_klmin'=>'required|in:L,P',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('siswa/'.$id.'/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $siswa->update($request->all());
    return redirect('siswa');
}
```

Where nisn is an unique attribute. Yet when I run it I always stumble in this screen written :

QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nisn1007' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `siswa` where `nisn1007` = 1007)

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `,` here:

```
'nisn'=>'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn'.$request->input('nisn'),
```

should be like this:

```
'nisn'=>'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn,'.$request->input('nisn'),
```

after: `siswa,nisn`

Comment: so I can't sleep for one day because a missing coma,,, thanks for the help dude, appreciate.